# R - Create a boundingbox, convert to Polygon class and Plot

Tags: r, rgdal

I have the  `NE lat lng` and `SW lat lng`.  My goal is simple, I am using RStudio and I want to create a bounding box from the above two lats and longs  and then generate Polygon and I want to add random points into the square polygon.
I have NELat/Lng and SW-Lat/Lng in a csv file that I could import into a data.frame.

I just need a little guidance to get started, Im very new to R language, its really different to what i am used to.

So far I have this:

```
coords = cbind(78.46801, 19.53407)
coordsmax = cbind(78.83157, 19.74557 )
sp = SpatialPoints(coordsmax)
sp2 = SpatialPoints(coords)

r1 = rbind(coords, coordsmax[1, ])  # join
P1 = Polygon(r1)
Ps1 = Polygons(list(P1), ID = "a")
plot(Ps1)
```

I just saw some examples elsewhere but I am not able to plot a polygon of 4 corners.

Comment: You only have a single duplicated coordinate in r1, is that meant to be 'r1 = rbind(coords, coordsmax)`  ??

Comment: Yes, corrected it. It still doesnt work though

Comment: Working through problems carefully one a time is a good way to get a solution.  I consider it a bug that Polygon() does not error when given only two or one coordinates, I've noted this in the sp issues. For you q,  library(raster);  SPs1 <- as(extent(r1), "SpatialPolygons");  plot(SPs1)

Comment: i am sorry that i have to use the answer function of stackexchange but my reputation is not high enough to comment.
@dof1985 you use (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (x_max, y_min), (x_min, y_min) as coordinates to create the polygon. i have tried the same, but failed. then i looked closer at your example and examined, that you use instead of (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_min),... following (x_min, y_min), (x_min, y_max),... could this be the reason of my error? please correct your example :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few changes have been made to your code:

First, note that I dropped the points creation. You can form a polygon without the use of `SpatialPoints`. Though in case many point are involved it would be better to create a polygon from points.

Second, I wrote 5 couples of coordinates in the matrix below.each coordinate couple stand for one corner of your bounding box, and the fifth repeats the first point. Namely the matrix includes: [**(x_min, y_min)**,  (x_max, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (x_max, y_min), **(x_min, y_min)**]

Finally, I used `SpatialPolygons` with `espg:4326` to form a plot-able object within a geographic context.

```
library(sp)

coords = matrix(c(78.46801, 19.53407,
               78.46801, 19.74557,
               78.83157, 19.74557,
               78.83157, 19.53407,
               78.46801, 19.53407), 
             ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)


P1 = Polygon(coords)
Ps1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P1), ID = "a")), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
plot(Ps1, axes = TRUE)
```

This is what happens If I plot your code:

[image: A polygon that looks like a line]

and this is after code modifications presented here:

[image: Bonding Box]

Comment: thats it! Could you comment a little bit on `proj4String` ? are you defining characteristics of a lat and long through it?

Comment: Hit `?is.projected` in R-console to see the `proj4string` help. Yes it is used to define CRS class to a spatial object

Answer (score 27):

You can nest the `extent` function, from the raster library, in `as` to create a SpatialPolygons object.

```
library(sp)
e <- as(raster::extent(78.46801, 78.83157, 19.53407, 19.74557), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(e) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
plot(e)
```

Comment: this looks like a better way than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, you can just simply use the `bbox2SP` function from the rgeos package - below is an example:

```r
library(rgeos)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> rgeos version: 0.5-2, (SVN revision 621)
#>  GEOS runtime version: 3.6.1-CAPI-1.10.1 
#>  Linking to sp version: 1.4-1 
#>  Polygon checking: TRUE

my_box <- rgeos::bbox2SP(n = 19.74557, s = 19.53407, w = 78.83157, e = 78.46801,
                         proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
plot(my_box)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>